# Getting Connection to mysql database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, applet

I am having problem in connecting to mysql database when I am using this code.I have already checked that port number is 3128.So there is no issue about that.I checked it and I think problem is in

```
connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3128/gcc","root", "root");
```

There is no error when compiling.Can someone help me with this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
//import java.net.*;

public class Main extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
 TextArea tarea;
 Button bsubmit;

 public void init()
 {
  setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
  setForeground(Color.white);

  Label l1=new Label("Write your code : ");
  l1.setFont(new Font("lucida console",Font.PLAIN,25));
  l1.setSize(200,30);

  tarea=new TextArea();
  tarea.setFont(new Font("lucida console",Font.PLAIN,18));
  tarea.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
  tarea.setSize(600,250);

  bsubmit=new Button("Submit");
  bsubmit.setFont(new Font("lucida console",Font.PLAIN,15));
  bsubmit.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
  bsubmit.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
  bsubmit.setSize(100,30);

  add(l1);
  add(tarea);
  add(bsubmit);

  setLayout(null);
  l1.setLocation(40,40);
  tarea.setLocation(40,100);
  bsubmit.setLocation(40,400);

  bsubmit.addActionListener(this);
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {
  if(ae.getSource()==bsubmit)
  {
   Connection connection=null;
   try 
   {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3128/gcc","root", "root");
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE test2 (code VARCHAR(254))");
   } 
   catch (Exception e) {}
  }  
 }
}
```

Comment: what kind of problem? it times out? permission denied? access denied?

Comment: Does it work if you change `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3128/gcc` to `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3128/gcc`?  You should also print the exception message in the catch block so you can see what error is occurring.

Comment: An empty catch block is one of the worst things you can do to yourself.  Print the stack trace, for goodness sake.  Check to see if you can access that database using the MySQL admin.  If it can't, it's unlikely that Java can.  Why use any port other than the standard 3306?  What did you accomplish by changing?

Comment: This could be a silly question but have you added the MySQL JDBC jar in your classpath?

Comment: I also checked out with 127.0.0.1 but still its not working. When I used the port 3306, there was an error.So I just checked my.conf in mysql directory in C Drive and there I got port number as 3128.My problem is when I click on Submit button in Applet, nothing happens i.e. table doesn't create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java database drivers are the worst thing. I remember, I had my first JDBC driver (or let's say: a working transaction;) to be installed within "only" 2 days, and I know a guy who had two weeks, lol.

In most of the time the very last issue is a SQL problem. Because you need to give the rights to the user as "username"@"IP". You find the user information in the database information_schema in the table user_privileges. There exist enough tutorials how to handle them, but I like 'username'@'%' to get all privileges in a test environment. *smile*

This may help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/adding-users.html

Yeah, those damn SQL rights... ;D

@Luiggi: That's certainly no silly question! I had hours to find that out!! I mean, which beginner knows that the Java sql classes are only xxxxxxx interfaces with no implemented code?! %D

**EDIT**

And anyway:

```
Class.forName("...driverblabla...");
```

Does this code line look like Java? Nooo, its a xxxxxx compiler hack or whatever! But it works, it really DOES something!!

Oh, but for certain driver implementations this won't work, you need this:

```
Class.forName("...driverblabla...").newInstance();
```

LMAO!

@Abhinav: Add this line above your getConnection-line:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver").newInstance();
```

And don't think one second about what it exactly does (I know it, but...let's screw it ;)